# Docker nodemon doesn't hot reload even though the volumes has been set up

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

So I have a simple node js app that I want to dockerize.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    random: Math.random(),
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

And here's the package.json file

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
```

To dockerize it and make my development easier I create a Dockerfile and docker-compose file for it like so

```
FROM node:18-alpine

RUN npm install -g nodemon

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm", "run" ,"dev" ]
```

```
services:
  api:
    build: .
    container_name: random-api
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    environment:
      - PORT=8080
    ports:
      - "4000:8080"
```

As you can see I have set up the docker volumes, but strangely the nodemon is not reloading when the code change. am I missing something? what should I do to make the dockerize app reflect the change

Comment: Can you please disclose the host OS?  (Is this Docker for Windows?)

Comment: actually I'm on Linux, ubuntu to be exact, the funny thing is, when I added the -L on nodemon, it now works, do you know why?

Comment: What happens if you just `npm run dev` directly on the host system?  Why bring Docker into the picture at all?

Comment: I want to learn docker, but get something strange like that, when I run `npm run dev` the nodemon working just fine outside of docker, but in docker if we didn't specify the `L` flag, it won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Docker for Windows watching a mapped folder, you need to use `nodemon --legacy-watch`.

User Meyey said [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/in-docker-windows-nodemon-does-not-detect-file-changes/135042):

> If you write data into the Windows folder mapped to the container path, it bypasses the Linux kernel and as such inotify never receives a filesystem event.  You need to use **[legacy mode](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/faq.md#help-my-changes-arent-being-detected)**.

Comment: Actually I'am on linux, but somehow when I added the -L on nodemon, it now works, why is that?